# HTML5 Video aspect ratio incorrect on Android

Tags: javascript, css, browser, html5-video, aspect-ratio

I'm using the following CSS code on my video element:

```
height: 466px;
width: 824px;
```

On my Mac (in Chrome, Firefox and Safari), it works fine. But on my Android tablet (Chrome, Firefox, Dolphin), the aspect ratio seems to be locked at 4:3 (although the video is 16:9) and therefore the video is squashed horizontally with black bars on either side.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the pixel aspect ratio is different...
try this list

http://www.bigbossmas.com/web-development/list-of-mobile-device-sizes/

and explanation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294571.aspx

PS Pixel aspect ratio is not the same as the image aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is really old, but didn't found a solution anywhere. So this is just for all those looking for a solution.

I fixed that problem inserting `style="object-fit: fill"` in the `<video>` tag.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­